# Hiding the gray border of the ZedGraph control

Tags: c#, controls, border, zedgraph

How do I remove the gray border of the ZedGraph control?

Just the graph should be in the form, without the gray border, label, and an title.

I tried to solve the problem with

```
_zgc.MasterPane.Border.Width = 0;
_zgc.MasterPane.Border.IsVisible = false;
```

but for now without success.

Comment: user1579585, I have tried to use the latest version of ZedGraph in a new Visual Studio project, and I don't see any gray borders. Can you add a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
GraphPane _gp = _zgc.GraphPane;
_gp.Margin.All = 0;
_gp.Legend.IsVisible = false;
_gp.Title.IsVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your are using the Masterpane instead of the Graphpane.

```
_zgc.GraphPane.Border.IsVisible = false;
_zgc.GraphPane.Legend.IsVisible = false;
_zgp.GraphPane.Title.IsVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide everything but the chart content:

```
zedGraph.GraphPane.Title.IsVisible = false;
zedGraph.GraphPane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
zedGraph.GraphPane.YAxis.IsVisible = false;
zedGraph.GraphPane.Border.IsVisible = false;
zedGraph.GraphPane.Chart.Border.IsVisible = false;
```

You can also remove the gap between chart pane and control borders:

```
zedGraph.GraphPane.Margin.All = -1;
```